# Submitting AJAX form old style

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form for which I want to use AJAX only for validation. It has several fields and I am currently using a PHP script which I want only to check if the size of the files entered into the input fields adds to less than N Kb. That works. Now what I would like is, once I see that the total size of the files is less than N, have the form submit to self in the old way:

action="localhost" method="post"

How can I achieve that same behaviour. Thank you very much

Comment: `currently using a PHP script which I want only to check if the size of the files entered into the input fields adds to less than N Kb` you can also do this in client side after checking or doing validation do the submit

Comment: if you are using this approach be aware if the user simply deactivates javascript you may receive invalid form data

Comment: Thanks , I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Sakuto said, you should have 1 validation function that first does the AJAX validation and then allows the form submission.

Something along the lines of:

```
function my_form_validation(e) {
  form_is_valid = validate_form_via_ajax();
  if (form_is_valid) {
    return true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false
}
```

And your form submit event should be bound to my_form_validation()

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/p8Lehqdg/3/

Comment: And if the ajax returns true, how do I send the form data as if it were an old fashion non ajax post form?

Comment: The "return true;" will allow your form to be submitted the regular way. (Returning false will block the form from submitting)

Comment: Thanks, that works, showing the log entry, but the form does not submit, I don't know if this is too stupid a question but what code should i add to submit the form? I tried adding $('form#conversionForm').submit(); but it goes into the loop, and the data in the form does not seem to be sent

Comment: I want to submit it loading another page, not as an ajax request, but sending the entries of the form as post variables to another page, like old style forms

Comment: My bad, the e.preventDefault() was placed too early in the validation function. Checkout this example: https://jsfiddle.net/p8Lehqdg/3/ (it will only do the e.preventDefault() if the ajax validation fails)

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I needed. Thank you very much for all the examples

Comment: It doesnt wait for the ajax callback

Answer (score 3):

You are basically catching the event, if you want to stop the current event you'll use `e.preventDefault()`, if you don't put this line / return `true` the action will simply continue.

Comment: Once I prevent the default behaviour, how do i add the other behavior? (regular post to self)

Comment: Thanks, this answer was valid too.